Why imperfect subjunctive?
Sto studiando il congiuntivo proprio adesso, e sto cercando di capire quanto segue:
Perché l'autore dovrebbe usare il congiuntivo imperfetto in questo passaggio, invece del condizionale?
Quale sarebbe il congiuntivo “innesco” in questa frase?

Non potevo smettere di farlo, cercando la scintilla che risvegliasse la mia ispirazione, tracciando una trama che mi riportasse al centro dell'attenzione.


Perché dovrebbe usare il condizionale? In generale in italiano non si usa il condizionale in una subordinata. Per caso sei un parlante tedesco o qualche altra lingua che usa la stessa forma per il congiuntivo e il condizionale?
